# Сгенерировать куки при динамичной подгрузки страницы

Tags: node.js, cookie

Делаю авторизацию над одном сайте, и возникли некоторые трудности с получением определенных кук. Основная проблема возникает после успешной авторизации, где для получения новой страницы с данными необходимы 2 куки, которые генерируются благодаря подгруженному js-файлу (`n.js`).

Файл выглядит следующим образом, иногда меняется значения `t` при повторных попытках.

```
if (typeof(n_js_once_lock) == 'undefined') {
    (function() {
        var d = document;
        var g = 0;
        var a = d.createElement('canvas');
        if (a) {
            var x = a.getContext('2d');
            var t = +[] + +[+[+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]]] + +[+[+!+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]]] + +[+[+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+[]]] + +[+[+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[]] + [+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+[]]] + +[+[+!+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]]] + +[+[+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+[]] + [+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[]]] + +[+[+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]] + [+!+[]] + [+!+[] + !+[] + !+[]]];
            var e = function(stdlib) {
                'use asm';
                var s = stdlib.Math.sqrt;
                var i = 0;
                var t = 0;
                var g = 0;

                function h() {
                    return g | 0;
                }
                function a(n) {
                    n = +n;
                    t = ~~s(n);
                    for (i = 3;
                    (i | 0) < (t | 0); i = (i | 0) + 2 | 0) {
                        g = (g | 0) + 1 | 0;
                        if (n % +(i | 0) == +0) {
                            t = ~~ (n / +(i | 0) + +(i | 0));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return t | 0;
                }
                return {
                    a: a,
                    h: h
                };
            }(window);
            var t1 = Date.now();
            t = e.a(t);
            g = e.h();
            t1 = Date.now() - t1;
            if (x) {
                var m = new Image();
                m.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAABCAIAAAAw6DswAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAB3RJTUUH5AYBEika0HtwfgAAAChJREFUCNdlikEKwDAAg/T/j3aHUCidByESKw4qUKnzJheLT///V4APg00X/61h1/YAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMjAtMDYtMDFUMTg6NDE6MjYrMDA6MDCGyuSQAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDIwLTA2LTAxVDE4OjQxOjI2KzAwOjAw95dcLAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
                m.onload = function() {
                    x.drawImage(m, 0, 0);
                    var h = 0;
                    for (var i = 31; 0 <= i; i--) {
                        var c = x.getImageData(i, 0, 1, 1).data;
                        h = h * 2;
                        0 < c[0] && h++;
                    }
                    h ^= t;
                    0 > h && (h += 4294967296);
                    d.cookie = 'n_js_t=1591036886;path=/;secure';
                    d.cookie = 'n_js_d=' + h + ';path=/;secure';
                    var m1 = new Image();
                    m1.src = '/n.gif?' + t1 + ',' + g;
                };
            } else {
                d.cookie = 'n_js_t=1;path=/;secure';
                var m1 = new Image();
                m1.src = '/n.gif?no2d';
            }
        } else {
            d.cookie = 'n_js_t=2;path=/;secure';
            var m1 = new Image();
            m1.src = '/n.gif?nocanvas';
        }
    })();
    var n_js_once_lock = true;
}
```

Структура всех запросов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После авторизации со страницы `auth` происходит редирект на `/profile/mycart`. Затем на этой странице подгружается `n.js`, в котором генерируются 2 куки (`n_js_t`, `n_js_d`), без которых нельзя получить запрос к `/dynamic/cart`.

Вопрос такой, можно ли как-нибудь сделать симуляцию у себя на сервере, чтобы получить эти самые куки? Были идеи выполнить эту часть на `nodejs`, но я не уверен на счет этого. Может есть другие пути?

Comment: Cookie - это строка, можете сгенерировать её на сервере

Comment: ну раз динамически подгружается n.js и генерируются куки, то динамически и считайте их перед запросом к /dynamic/cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос такой, можно ли как-нибудь сделать симуляцию у себя на сервере,
>   чтобы получить эти самые куки?

Да легко))) Вот, пожалуйста:
[Express](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) фреймворк для NodeJS
Подробное описание:

https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

http://expressjs.com/

**Пример:**

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/myapi', function(req, resp) {
   console.log(req.cookies['Your-Cookie-Name-Here']);
})
```